# How to make child components use map() from App.js props data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My react is 18.2. I want the child component to receive data and use map() from App.js.

I checked the child component received the data, but I don't know why does it can't use map().

It shows this error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

So do anyone can fix it? I guess this is render problem, but I don't know how to fix it, thank you.

fetched():

```
[
  { id:1, date: '2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { id:2, date: '2013-09-03T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { id:3, date: '2012-04-02T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { id:4, date: '2013-12-08T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { id:5, date: '2010-01-23T00:00:00.000Z' },
];
```

App.js:

```
import { Child } from './Child';

const Test = () => {
  const [toChild, setToChild] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = async () => {
      const fetchedData = await fetched();
      setToChild(fetchedData)
    };
    data();
  }, []);

  const test = () => {
    setToChild(fetchedData)
  }
}

return(<Child toChild={toChild}>)
```

Child.js:

```
const Child = ({ toChild }) => {
  const data = toChild;

  const getDate = data.map((item) => item.date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data coming from your fetch is an array of objects, you may want to initialize the state as an empty array `useState([])`, `useEffect` will fire once the component has been mounted so at first, `toChild` will be `undefined` and that's why you are getting that error.
So basically:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Child } from './Child';

const Test = ()=>{
const [toChild,setToChild] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const data = async () => {
      const fetchedData = await fetched();
      setToChild(fetchedData)
    };
    data();
  }, []);

return <Child toChild={toChild} />
```

Comment: Hi. About 'edit suggested', is it javascript question?

Comment: Yep, the tags are related and highly used / searched so it increases the question visibility. That way your question could help other users that might face this same problem in the future :)

Comment: Actually I thought it would only happen in react...because useState sets the initial value format only in react. Is there any chance I can know that tag is javascript reason?

Comment: Of course, this is a `react.js` related question but I think it's a good idea to include at least 2 related tags on questions and since `react` is a JavaScript library and the `javascript` tag is very popular, it would make sense to include it.

Comment: Can't use `usestate`?

Comment: `react-hooks` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Jsx is already rendered before javascript in react even though you fetch the data from server but html already rendered to the browser.so add any loading component to that. `toChild?:<div>loading</div>:<Child toChild={toChild}/>`